# Reset binding variable in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

When if we pass in a binding variable (like $saveDialog as true) to alert or sheet, the variable will reset to false after that.

```
.alert(isPresented: $saveDialog) {}
```

But what if we want to do the same thing: says clear the screen when we tap on the button, by setting the $clear to true:

```
 Button("Clear") { self.clear = true }
```

Then

```
 DrawView(clear:$clear)
```

And in DrawView

```
struct DrawView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var clear:Bool

    func updateUIView(_ canvas: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        if clear {
            canvas.drawing = PKDrawing()
            self.clear = false // Issue
        }
    }
```

The issue is: Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior. Where do I set the clear variable to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible solution

```
func updateUIView(_ canvas: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
    if clear {
        canvas.drawing = PKDrawing()

        // make on next event loop, so do not affect current update
        // which already uses `clear` state, thus avoid cycling
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.clear = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This DispatchQueue.main.async helped to resolve a very similar issue I was having. I am not sure I understand what putting the "self.clear = false" inside DispatchQueue.main.async does though. Does it just tell the system to not execute that code in the closure until after the updateUIView() function is finished? How can you tell what order it will run the code in the closure?